# C Language: Change the contents of a string array

Tags: c, arrays, string, assign

I'm having trouble changing the contents of a variable holding a string. I'm probably thinking of this too literally compared to an int and not as an array. Maybe have to flush array first?
Much thanks.

```
// declare with maximum size expected +1 (for terminator 0)
char myString1[20] = "Hello"; //declare and assign one line - OK
myString1[20] = "Hello Longer"; // change contents - fails
myString1[] = "Hello Longer"; // change contents - fails
myString1 = "Hello Longer"; // change contents - fails
```

Comment: Possible compile error?

Answer (score 2):

This is C, not an object oriented language that takes care of copying strings for you.  You'll need to use the `string` library.  For example:

```
char myString1[20] = "Hello";
strncpy(myString1, "Hello Longer", 20);
```

Comment: s/object oriented/any/gi... I'm sure you know that background work on string copying isn't just an object oriented paradigm.

Comment: @JeffLangemeier Sure.  My point was C doesn't have a string class, for example.

Comment: Thanks Fiddling. 
Yes, I'm coming from OOP so appreciate the fundamental change in mind set.
If I understand correct the var is not directly changed but rather copied into itself and overwrite old. Using strncpy() with args of name of target (=original), new contents, new size)
THanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a function like `strncpy` to copy a string.

Answer (score 0):

In C the assigment operator `=` does not work for arrays. With the only exception of initialisers.

---

More over this

```
myString1[20] = "Hello Longer"
```

is a type mismatch as `myString1[20]` is a `char` to which you obviously only can assign a `char` or something that can be converted to a `char`.

---

To trick this you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Str_s
{
  char myString[20];
};

int main(void)
{  
  struct Str_s str1 = {
    "Hello"
  };

  struct Str_s str2 = {
    "World"
  };

  printf("str1='%s'\nstr2='%s'\n", str1.myString, str2.myString);

  str2 = str1;

  printf("str1='%s'\nstr2='%s'\n", str1.myString, str2.myString);

  return 0;
}
```

This should print:

```
Hello World
Hello Hello
```

Obviously the assignment operator works for `struct`s.