# Really new to C, Having trouble with this basic code

Tags: c

I'm learning `C` "just started today" and I'm wondering why I can't run this code. I know this question is dumb but it would help a lot if someone explained it.

```
main()
{
char name;
name = "King";

printf("%c",name);

}
```

From what I've read, it all seems right.

Operands of `=` have incompatible types  `char` and `char *`.

If someone can explain that would help me alot!

I'm using the IDE: Pelles C for Windows.

Comment: [This](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html) tutorial might help you.

Comment: C doesn't have strings like high-level languages you might be used to. The type "char" is a single character--actually a single byte. The type "char *" is a pointer to a character; that is, a memory address.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Language: Change the contents of a string array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683119/c-language-change-the-contents-of-a-string-array)

Comment: Also, the C++ and C are two different languages.  If you are programming in C, remove the C++ tag.  One example is that C++ has a `std::string` type, whereas C doesn't.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title. It should be descriptive either of the problem you're having or the question you're asking, in a way that will be meaningful to a future user here who finds it in a search result. It's clear you're having trouble, or you wouldn't be asking here. It's also clear it's C, because you've tagged it as C. Removing both of those bits of information leaves *really new basic code*, which provides zero relevant information. Thanks.

Comment: Also, this *is* extremely basic code that should be covered in every single C programming book or tutorial. You'll probably save yourself a lot of grief by finding one and working your way through it; there's not a lot of patience here for users who won't even attempt to make an effort by working through a tutorial and expect us to tutor them instead. :-) I'm quite certain a Google or Bing search for *c programming tutorial* will turn up quite a few from which you can choose.

Answer (score 4):

In your code, `name` is just a `char`.

OTOH, `"King"` is called a *string literal*. You need to have a `char` pointer to hold the base address of the string literal.

Change your code to

```
char *name;
```

That said, to print a string, you need `%s` format specifier. Use it like

```
printf("%s",name);
```

Suggestion: The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you clairfy further more and give somewhat more details, not alot though! Thanks

Comment: It was the recommended signature, the OP probably used an old book, now it has to be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Comment: Why does main() work then? or int main()? what's the difference between 
main(), int main (), and int main (void)
I'm really curious now haha

Comment: @GasM None, but I believe the default return type of `int` - that is used when you use `main()`- is deprecated or being deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

In C, declaring a variable as "char" means your variable can only hold one character. i.e. 'a', 'b', '-', '=', etc.

If you wish to hold more characters, i.e. a string, you need to declare the char variable according to the character length of what you want to copy to your variable.

In your case, if you wish to assign "King" to name, name must be declared as such:

```
char name[5] = "King";
```

Note that we declare name as size 5 because the last character of a string is the invisible null character '\0'. Because C doesn't have an inbuilt string type   but an array of chars, we need the null character to indicate that we have reached the "end of the current string." Also note that if you use the "string.h" header function "strlen", which gives you the length of the string, the return value doesn't include the null character. So, calling `strlen(name)` would return "4" not "5". The null character is neglected.

If you wish to declare name first and THEN copy "King" to it, you can include the "string.h" header and use the strcpy function.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

int main(void){

    char name[5];
    strcpy(name,"King");
    printf("%s", name);

return 0;
}
```

You cannot assign string literals to a char array as such: `name = "king";` in C.

I hope the code above wasn't too confusing as you're just starting out. It gets easier with practice!

Comment: I suggest you clarify why `name[5]` when "King" has 4 letters.  It may not be obvious to beginners.

Comment: Good call, added some clarification.

Comment: The information regarding what you can do in C++ is irrelevant, as this question is about C. It's a poor idea to confuse someone by including information about C++ when  they're clearly struggling to learn the basics of C.

Answer (score 0):

"char" designates just that: a single character.

To store a chain of characters, you need to use an array of chars or a pointer on a char like so:

```
char name[10]; //array of characters, stores up to 10, indexed from 0 to 9.

char *name; //pointer to a character, stores as many as you want, but beware of memory allocation.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do...

```
 char <name>[<Amount of space to allocate>] = "Whatever stuff here";
```

e.g. `char NotABrony[30] = ""`

Secondly, you cant use equal signs with chars. Instead use strcpy

```
strcpy(name, "Whatever stuff to put in here");
```

Thirdly, you use

```
printf("%s", name);
```

Because %c will give you the ascii value (You will learn that later)